# Ionic2: What is the best method to store static constants like api urls?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I would like to know the best method to store application wide static constants like API URLs and manage them in one place.

Comment: Check out this component https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

Comment: I tried setting the value in app.component.ts constructor config.set('', 'apiurl', 'http://xxx.example.com/xxx/api/'); .  But this.config.get('apiurl') returns null when I try to read the value in my page.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create enums and then import them into your files as follows:

create `enums.ts` and import it into your **.ts** file

```
export enum APIURL{
    URL1 = "http://example.com",
    URL2 = "http://example2.com"
}
```

and in your **component.ts** file

```
import * as Enums from './somedirectory/enums/enums';
...
constructor() 
{
    console.log(Enums.APIURL.URL1);
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the enums.ts file in the application structure? Inside app folder?

Comment: You can create inside src/enums/ folder. You have to create the folder ofcourse